# parse json using JsonModel

Tags: ios, iphone, jsonmodel

Facing problem while getting a array of json.

### I am using JsonModel library for json handelling.

My json data is:

```
[
    {
        "TSCard_id": 100,
        "TSCardBackend_id": "TSu1t1",
        "TSCard_date": "10/11/2013",
        "TSCard_resource_id": "",
        "TSCard_resource_name": "",
        "TSCard_job_id": "JOB_M2156 ",
        "TSCard_job_desc": "BAGARIA MILLIPORE - BOM ",
        "TSCard_activity_id": "B03",
        "TSCard_activity_desc": "Closing",
        "TSCard_hours": "4.0",
        "TSCard_chargeableflag": "0",
        "TSCard_desc": "Description:",
        "TSCard_syncflag": "0",
        "TSCard_flag": "",
        "user_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "TSCard_id": 101,
        "TSCardBackend_id": "TSu1t2",
        "TSCard_date": "12/11/2013",
        "TSCard_resource_id": "",
        "TSCard_resource_name": "",
        "TSCard_job_id": "JOB_B0002",
        "TSCard_job_desc": "ABB LIMITED - BLR ",
        "TSCard_activity_id": "NB01",
        "TSCard_activity_desc": "Admin  ",
        "TSCard_hours": "5.0",
        "TSCard_chargeableflag": "1",
        "TSCard_desc": "Description:",
        "TSCard_syncflag": "0",
        "TSCard_flag": "",
        "user_id": "1"
    }
]
```

Above json has 2 objects of type `TSCard class`

```
 //TSCard.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <JSONModel.h>

@protocol TSCard @end

@interface TSCard : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCardBackend_id;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_resource_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_resource_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_job_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_job_desc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_activity_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_activity_desc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_hours;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_chargeableflag;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_desc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_syncflag;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *TSCard_flag;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *user_id;

@end
```

And I am making a class for array of type `TSCard`

```
 //GetCardData.h

#import <JSONModel.h>
#import "TSCard.h"


@interface GetCardData : JSONModel

@property(strong,nonatomic)NSArray<TSCard>* myDataArray;

@end
```

then I parsing json as below:

```
NSError* err = nil;
GetCardData *c = [[GetCardData alloc] initWithString:jsonString error:&err];

    NSLog(@"%d",c.myDataArray.count);
```

NSLog Error:
Error Domain=JSONModelErrorDomain Code=1 "Invalid JSON data: Attempt to initialize JSONModel object using initWithDictionary:error: but the dictionary parameter was not an 'NSDictionary'." UserInfo=0x8265490 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid JSON data: Attempt to initialize JSONModel object using initWithDictionary:error: but the dictionary parameter was not an 'NSDictionary'.}

I can't find where I am wrong...can anybody suggest the right way of using `JsonModel` and parsing a jsonString to array of `TSCard` objects correctly.

Comment: Where is JSON parsing code ? can you show initWithString method and JSONModel class ?

Comment: what was facing issue to you

Comment: JSONModel is not commonly used, so you won't find many familiar with it.  But what is your `err` variable showing??

Comment: why don't you just use NSJSONSerialization? it is built in iOS SDK.

Comment: @Muhammad: by using this library no need of mapping every key to class object parameter..and parsing mannually

Comment: @Muhammad and Grzegorz Krukowski -- Apparently JSONModel is similar to those gosh-awful tools they like to use with Java that copy the JSON data directly into custom object instances.  They are a major source of problems for Java, but Java folks feel they must use them.  I was hoping they wouldn't appear in Objective-C, but I guess they will.

Comment: So what does `err` report???

Comment: @preetam but mapping every key to a class object is more handy IMO :)

Comment: (I suspect that JSONModel is lacking the clue to start with myDataArray, since there is nothing in the JSON by that name.  Probably JSONModel doesn't work so well if the outermost structure is an array vs an "object".)

Comment: @HotLicks: updated question with error msg.

Comment: Very likely you need to do something like `jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"{\"myDataArray\": %@ }", jsonString);`

Comment: (Note that very likely there is another init method in JSONModel that allows you to specify the starting name.)

Comment: @HotLicks: bro you rocked!!! It's working.

Comment: @preetam You should study the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSONModel/0.9.3/#) and try to understand how JSONModel works, I have answered.

Comment: @JanakNirmal: OK..thanks for answer..and will accept your suggestion

Comment: @HotLicks you can post answer and OP can accept yours as you suggested solution before me, if you wish.

Comment: @JanakNirmal - Nah, I don't do answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using following code for parsing your json and getting array

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [TSCard arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:jsonString];
```

Than create and assign

```
GetCardData *objCardData = [[GetCardData alloc] init];
objCardData.myDataArray = yourArray;
```

or you need to change your JSONString as follow

```
   {
    "myDataArray": [
        {
            "TSCard_id": 100,
            "TSCardBackend_id": "TSu1t1",
            "TSCard_date": "10/11/2013",
            "TSCard_resource_id": "",
            "TSCard_resource_name": "",
            "TSCard_job_id": "JOB_M2156 ",
            "TSCard_job_desc": "BAGARIA MILLIPORE - BOM ",
            "TSCard_activity_id": "B03",
            "TSCard_activity_desc": "Closing",
            "TSCard_hours": "4.0",
            "TSCard_chargeableflag": "0",
            "TSCard_desc": "Description:",
            "TSCard_syncflag": "0",
            "TSCard_flag": "",
            "user_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "TSCard_id": 101,
            "TSCardBackend_id": "TSu1t2",
            "TSCard_date": "12/11/2013",
            "TSCard_resource_id": "",
            "TSCard_resource_name": "",
            "TSCard_job_id": "JOB_B0002",
            "TSCard_job_desc": "ABB LIMITED - BLR ",
            "TSCard_activity_id": "NB01",
            "TSCard_activity_desc": "Admin  ",
            "TSCard_hours": "5.0",
            "TSCard_chargeableflag": "1",
            "TSCard_desc": "Description:",
            "TSCard_syncflag": "0",
            "TSCard_flag": "",
            "user_id": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Than your code will definitely work. Tell me if need more help.

Comment: need to change json string

Comment: Yeah I read comments now, I was busy writing answer :D, anyway you got help. Thax.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, I personally recommend [BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher). You don't have to do anything else or declare any protocol apart from your data model:

```
@interface TSCard : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCardBackend_id;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_resource_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_resource_name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_job_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_job_desc;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_activity_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_activity_desc;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_hours;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_chargeableflag;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_desc;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_syncflag;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *TSCard_flag;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString  *user_id;

@end
```

You can then get your array with one neatly short line:

```
NSArray *dataArray = [BWJSONMatcher matchJSON:jsonString withClass:[TSCard class]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using this method in `JSONModel`

```
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray <TSCard *> *yourArray = [TSCard arrayOfModelsFromString:strData error:&error];
```

and do your logic.